# Spotfire data table merge using nearest neighbour values

Tags: merge, spotfire

I am trying to merge two data tables (tables A and B) in Spotfire 7.10 using insert columns to give the resultant table C. My problem is i cannot get the join i need on Depth because Depth in tables A and B are not exact matches. What i need is to match Table B to Table A based on a match using Depth to its nearest value i.e Depth 10.5 (table B) matches Depth 10 (Table A). Is this possible in Spotfire or using an TERR R script?

**Table A**

```
Depth   data
10       2
20       4
30       3
40       5
50       7
```

**Table B**

```
Depth   data 2
10.5     100
30.5     112
50.5     125
```

**Table C**

```
Depth   data    data 2
10      2       100
20      4
30      3       112
40      5
50      7       125
```

many thanks for any help

Comment: Why don't you expect Depth = 20 in Table A to match to Depth = 10.5 in Table B? It is in fact the nearest value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the range of values you may have in both tables for Depth, but you may find that simply rounding the result to the nearest 10 in Table B will suffice. Then you can join based on this.

```
Round([Depth]/10,0)*10
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the help in this case i have got this to work as needed. Sometimes though the range of values for Depth in table A can be very close and contain non rounded numbers so this may struggle then. Guess i would have to round each table and then join.